# Convert Id to string type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

The model represents a simple object with an Id. The Id is mapped to a DB column which is also a number type. But the requirement is to pass both Id in number and string format to the client. It's required since the Id is a bigInt and some of the client apps does not support bigInt type hence a string variation should be passed to the client.

However, this string id is not present in the DB. So it's something that has to be generated on the fly. Is there a way to achieve this in the mapping onModelCreating?

I tried using Hasconversion() but no luck so far.

```cs
 public class Model
 {
   public long ModelId { get; set; }
   public string ModelIdString { get; set; }
   public decimal ModelValue { get; set; }
 }
```

```cs
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

         //configure column names
         modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().ToTable("db_model", "user_dba");


         modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(p =>
         {
             p.Property(md => md.ModelId).HasColumnName("model_id");
             p.Property(md => md.ModelIdString).HasColumnName("model_id").HasConversion<string>();
             p.Property(md => md.ModelValue).HasColumnName("value");
          });
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you add one more property in your Model class?

Comment: One more property? Like what.

Comment: Public string ModelIDString {get, set}, in your class, you can convert your ModelID to ModelIDString use method?

Comment: Use a another model and map it to the one used by the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't advise to make changes to the model only because of the client application requirements.
Instead create dedicated class which represents data structure required for the client applications and map database model to the client data structure.

This will isolate database model from client requirements, give you freedom to design database without dependency on client requirements. Also it will protect your model from possible future changes on client side.
For example you can expose only fields client suppose to see, but hide fields critical for your own application.

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string SecretKey { get; set; } // "hidden" from the client
}

public class ClientModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When you retrieve model from database map it to the client model

```
var clientModel = dbContext.Models
    .Where(model => model.Id = someId)
    .Select(model => new ClientModel
    {
        Id = model.Id.ToString(),
        Value = model.Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

Or you can create extension method for the model

```
public static ClientModel ToClientModel(this Model model)
{
    return new ClientModel
    {
        Id = model.Id.ToString(),
        Value = model.Value
    };
}

var clientModel = dbContext.Models
    .Where(model => model.Id = someId)
    .Select(model => model.ToClientModel())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio for the detailed example. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since string id is not present in the DB, you can exclude ModelIdString property from mapping.

```
public class Model
{
    public long ModelId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ModelIdString
    {
        get { return ModelId.ToString(); }
    }
    public decimal ModelValue { get; set; }
}

public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //configure column names
        modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().ToTable("db_model", "user_dba");


        modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(p =>
        {
            p.Property(md => md.ModelId).HasColumnName("model_id");
            p.Property(md => md.ModelValue).HasColumnName("value");
        });
    }
}
```